# On the normal crossing divisor of $\overline{\mathcal M}_g$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, complex-geometry, algebraic-curves, moduli-spaces

Let $g\geq 2$ be an integer. Let $\overline{\mathcal M}_g$ denote the DM stack of stable curves of genus $g$. It is well-known that the moduli stack is smooth and has a natural normal-crossing divisor given by the locus of singular curves.

1. Is it a simple normal crossing divisor?
2. How many components does it have?
3. Is there a description of each of the components?

(By a simple normal crossing divisor, I mean a normal crossing divisor such that every component is smooth.)

Comment: Please look at the original paper of Deligne and Mumford. There is one component parametrizing curves with one node, and $\left[\dfrac{g}{2}\right] $ components corresponding to the union of two curves of genus $p$ and $q$ with $p+q=g$.

Comment: @abx thanks for the comment. There are many other components, though, right? I was asking whether the description of the components is well known. Is there any reference where I can find these descriptions?

Comment: It's not snc since many of the components intersect themselves.

Comment: @Will Sawin Ok, I am very confused with various notions around the normal crossing divisors, namely strict, simple, double...etc. What I mean by simple normal crossing here is that the divisor is a normal crossing divisor such that every component is smooth.

Comment: The components are exactly those I described above. You'll find this in any introduction to $\overline{\mathscr{M}}_g$, in particular the paper by Deligne and Mumford.

Comment: @abx thank you. So the number of components is always $[g/2]+1$. Right? Also, I have browse through a lot of notes on $\overline{\mathcal M}_g$, but I have never found any discussion on this. It will be very helpful if you can suggest some notes.

Comment: @abx also, from what you said, I guess that the moduli space can be nicely stratified in terms of the number of nodes in the stable curves, where the generic points of the divisor correspond to curves with only one node. The generic curves of the next strata are curves with exactly two nodes and so on. Maybe the stratification can be defined in terms of the vanishing loci of the Fitting ideal of the relative cotangent sheaf of the universal curve.

Comment: Yes, the components are not smooth, because they intersect themselves. For example, the component of irreducible nodal curves has a self-intersection, and thus a singularity, at the locus of irreducible curves with two nodes.

Comment: @S.D. If you want to understand all the boundary strata, the keywords are clutching and gluing maps. The boundary strata are indexed by certain graphs and there are morphisms of moduli spaces that describe them. A reference is Geometry of Algebraic Curves Vol II, Chapter 12.

Comment: @Dori Bejleri thanks for the reference, this is what I was looking for!!